# Accessing a user input field name that contains a space

Tags: php, input, get, aweber

I have a situation; I know that we can print data from query string like this;

```
 <?
 $firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
 echo $firstname;
 ?>
```

Issue is, I have a form with firstname and lastname fields with space in its name, like this;

```
<input type="text" class="text" name="name (awf_first)" value=""  onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="500" />
<input id="awf_field-72073394-last" class="text" type="text" name="name (awf_last)" value=""  onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="501" />
```

So in this situation I need to print first name and last name on the success page of form submit. What approach should I use?

I tired to do these two things but it didn't worked;

```
$firstname = $_GET['name%20(awf_first)'];
echo $firstname;
```

and the second approach

```
 $firstname = urldecode($_GET['name (awf_first)']);
 echo $firstname;
```

Please note, that its not possible to remove space from names of the input on form.

Thanks,

Comment: vardump it ... see how it is displayed

Comment: Why you use `%20` instead of just space?

Comment: `$firstname = $_GET['name (awf_first)'];`?

Comment: Why would anyone put spaces and parentheses in input names to begin with is the real question.

Comment: @Mathematician171 when using get the querystring replaces ' ' with %20

Comment: @Mathematician171 used space as well but it didn't work either

Comment: @Devon basically its a form built on aweber, so its not in my control to eliminate space from the field name, if I remove this the field record will not be saved to aweber

Comment: @user3550203, did you do a var_dump like others suggested?

Comment: @Devon yes just did and it sorted out the issue. totally forgot before to use var_dump.

Comment: @user3550203 So it converts the space to an underscore?  Select that as the correct answer in case anyone else comes across this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `%20` just use `_`. Your code will be

```
$firstname = urldecode($_GET['name_(awf_first)']);
echo $firstname;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try a var_dump($_GET) to see the index name given to your field.

```
<?php var_dump($_GET); ?>
```

Comment: perfect solution mate. Thanks alot, this sorted out the issue :)